# xPages throwing error on code in this.rendered

Tags: xpages

I have an xPages application that uses the one ui application layout.  I have a custom control with a navigator and several different tree nodes.

I have some code to render or not based on a value from one of my beans.  It works great for my basic leaf node but when I use the same code in a basic container node I get an error saying that aPropertyProfile is null.  The bean is loaded just fine in the parent xPage and the rendered code of the basic leaf node works fine.  I suspect this has to do with csjs vs. ssjs but when adding the computed render code for the basic container node it says Javascript ( ServerSide ).

Any thoughts why this isn't working?

```
<xe:basicContainerNode label="Register for e-Statements" submitValue="RegisterForEstatements" enabled="true">
    <xe:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:if( aPropertyProfile.getStatementCoupon_1().equalsIgnoreCase( "Statements" ) )
       return true;
    else
        return false;}]]>
    </xe:this.rendered>
</xe:basicContainerNode>

<xe:basicLeafNode label="Register for e-Statements" onClick="linkToEstatementsSignup();">
   <xe:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
         if( aPropertyProfile.getStatementCoupon_1().equalsIgnoreCase( "Statements" ) )
              return true;
         else
              return false;
   }]]></xe:this.rendered>
</xe:basicLeafNode>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works for me is isolating my beans in a SSJS wrapper, it might work for you too. So you would write:

```
<xe:basicContainerNode label="Register for e-Statements" submitValue="RegisterForEstatements" enabled="true">
    <xe:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:myDisplay.renderStatements()}]]>
    </xe:this.rendered>
</xe:basicContainerNode>
```

and in a SSJS library you add:

```
 var myDisplay = {
     /* Show the e-statement node */
     "renderStatements" : function() {
              var result = false;
              try {
                  result = aPropertyProfile.getStatementCoupon_1().equalsIgnoreCase( "Statements" );
              } catch (e) {
                  print(e.message);
              }
              return result;
      },

     /*Do other stuff */
     "renderAdvanced" : function() {

     }
 }
```

Using this approach you have clean XPages source and can add better error handling to the calls. It also could sort out what looks like a timing issue.

Comment: Thanks so much Stephen.  That did the job.  Is this considered a best practice then to use a function in a script library to do the heavy lifting and call that code in the xPage?  Along the lines of keeping the xPage just the View so to speak?

Comment: I don't know much about "best practises" :-). What works for me: keep the XPage itself as light as possible and try to use domain specific expressions (or Domain Specific Language) rather than implementation details there. myDisplay.renderStatements() should clearly say what the call does, but not reveal how. So you check the XPage and more or less should be able to read it loud with a tech-savvy business user understanding what you say.